# Why I can't migrate index to my database scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generate a table by using

rails generate model Relationship follower_id:integer followed_id:integer

Then, I add my index as follows

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

After that I ran rake db:migrate
  `rake db:migrate`

```
== 20170922165845 CreateRelationships: migrating ==============================

-- create_table(:relationships)

-> 0.0010s

== 20170922165845 CreateRelationships: migrated (0.0011s) =====================
```

Why is it not migrating index?

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170922181915) do 
  #...
  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t| 
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false 
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false 
  end
  #...
end
```

Comment: This migrated...how do you know the indexes didn't work?

Comment: There is nothing in the schema

Comment: Does your DB exist and your database.yml?

Comment: Yesbaban3076:~/workspace (master) $ rails generate model Relationship 
Running via Spring preloader in process 5456
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20170922181915_create_relationships.rb
      create    app/models/relationship.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/relationship_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/relationships.yml

Comment: can you show your schema?

Comment: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170922181915) do

    create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

Comment: @babandeepsingh search your `schema.rb`.  Look at my answer below, if you add indexes like you did they won't appear IN the `create_table` block. In your schema in your question you've removed everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your commands in a brand new rails (version 4.2 and ruby 2.3.4) project and everything works as expected.  I would `rake db:rollback` and delete the files and try it again.

**My Steps:**

I ran `rails generate model Relationship follower_id:integer followed_id:integer`

Then edited the newly created migration to add indexes as follows:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

ran `rake db:migrate`
opened schema.rb and had **NOTICE the indexes are outside the `create_table` block**:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170922191347) do

  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"

end
```

Comment: Still not working bro. I am not a coder, I am just trying to learn